# UI Bootstrap Typeahead $digest already in Progress

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Got $digest is already in progress when trying to populate data from $http.get

And here is my code

JSON result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 14,
    "name": "RIAU"
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "name": "KEPULAUAN RIAU"
  }
]
```

Controller:

```
    $scope.getProvince = function(value) {
      return $http.get('/api/v1/province', {
        params: {
          q: value
        }
      }).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
   }
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
          <!-- Province -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Province</label>
            <input type="text" uib-typeahead="province for province.name in getProvince($viewValue)" placeholder="{{ province }}"
              typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-no-results="noResults"
              class="form-control" ng-model="cat.customer.anchor_residence_1.province">
            <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
            <div ng-show="noResults">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Do you want to pass the `input` value to the function `getProvince`?

Comment: Yes i do exactly the same from ui bootstrap example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getProvince function returns Promise, not real data. you have to separate saving data and listing data.

```
... in provinces ... ng-keydown=getProvince($viewValue) ... in html
```

### #

Problem is to mixed angular digest cycle.

1) getProvince called in digest cycle (in html)
2) getting data from server, before completed return promise.
3) getProvinxe again, because promise is not list. so "falling in digest cycle in digest cycle". Error occured.